# LocationManager never triggers, Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-location

I need to get the current location, saved these to a `Bundle` and forward them to a `BroadCastReceiver`, which will trigger every 5th second. This is how I structured my code

```
public class GPSServiceActivity extends Activity {

public Bundle locationBundle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationBundle = new Bundle();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    getCurrentLocation();

    Intent intent = new Intent(GPSServiceActivity.this, GPSHandler.class);
    intent.putExtra("Latitude", locationBundle.getDouble("Latitude"));
    intent.putExtra("Longitude", locationBundle.getDouble("Longitude"));
    // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request
    // code instead of 192837
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000,
            sender);
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            5000, 0, mlocListener);

}

/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {



    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        double Latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        double Longitude = loc.getLongitude();

        locationBundle.putDouble("Longitude", Longitude);
        locationBundle.putDouble("Latitude", Latitude);

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

    }
}
```

}

My `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

After some time debugging the code, I found out that the `MyLocationListener` never triggers, the `Bundle locationBundle` just contains two double with the value 0.0 and 0.0. Can somebody give me a hint on how to get this up and running?

**EDIT**

Just for test purposes I wrote this code

```
List<String> providers = mlocManager.getAllProviders();

        if(providers.size() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
                Log.i("Providers: ", providers.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        else
            Log.i("Providers: ", "No providers");
```

And this outputs

```
network
gps
passive
```

Comment: are you testing it on emulator?

Comment: Yeah as the guy above said, If you're testing it on an emulator then you need to send a test location to the emulator or it will just bug out. check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950389/android-emulator-finding-mock-user-location-coordinates-having-problems

Comment: Move your LOcation Provider setup to onStart instead of onCreate; Check if your provider is enabled: locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Comment: @TanjaV The network provider is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if provider is enabled. ask user to enable if its not. Check last argument in updateLocationRequest call. what is mlocListener? is it object of your location listener class(MyLocationListener )?

Comment: The user doesn't need to enable the provider, if the provider is `NETWORK_PROVIDER` as in my case.

Comment: try getLastKnownLocation() ? i dont know if that helps but just to check if you get any location at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
MyLocationOverlay
```

it is method in [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay#drawMyLocation%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20android.location.Location,%20com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20long%29)

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: You said:"I need to get the current location .... " `onLocationChanged` ... do you check this event? ... i use it to geoposition ... onSensorChanged ...